# Different output, same line?

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm a newbie trying to follow along to this tutorial from freeCodeCamp [(building a discord bot)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8o25pRbXdFw) and I'm using the Atom text editor and running my program on the command line.

The code that I'm having issue with is here:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    console.log(guild.name)

    guild.channels.forEach((channel) => {
      console.log(' - ${channel.name} (${channel.type}) - ${channel.id}')
    });
  });
});
```

This line is supposed to get a list of channels from a server

```
console.log(' - ${channel.name} (${channel.type}) - ${channel.id}')
```

This is what the code looks like in my editor: [image]

When I start the program, I get a faulty output.

```
Logged in as Bot!
Server
 - ${channel.name} (${channel.type}) - ${channel.id}
 - ${channel.name} (${channel.type}) - ${channel.id}
```

So I try copy and pasting/replacing the exact same line of code from the tutorial and it appears different in my editor:[image]

I run the code and it works with correct output.

```
Logged in as Bot!
Server
 -- Text Channels (category) - 142430248239302402
 -- Voice Channels (category) - 132932823293932239
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the first case, you have single quotes (`'`), which delimit a normal string literal. In the second case, you have backticks (`\` `), which delimit a template string literal. The former is not capable of interpolation (using `${...}` to insert stuff); the latter one is.

Comment: Note that you used the correct quotes (backticks) earlier in the code--just looking, *really looking*, e.g., seeing explicitly what is actually there instead of *assuming* a detail, is often enough to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you have single quotes `'`, which work to delimit a normal string literal. In the second case, you have back-ticks `` ` ``, which delimit a [template string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The former is not capable of interpolation (using `${...}` to insert stuff) while the later one is.

Notice below:

```js
guild.channels.forEach((channel) => {
  console.log(` - ${channel.name} (${channel.type}) - ${channel.id}`)
});
```